# Is it possible to keep appsettings.json editable post-deployment when using the "Produce single file" publish option for VS2019 / .Net Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I have a simple console app which needs to load its configuration from `appsettings.json`. I'm publishing from VS2019 using the "Produce single file" option.

The default behaviour is for publish to place `appsettings.json` inside the single file. That's no good to me because I want to be able to edit the configuration file in-place on the Linux server where it will be deployed.

It's possible to exclude `appsettings.json` from the bundled file by adding an option to its entry in the project file - `<ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>` works great and causes VS2019 to publish the appsettings.json file alongside the binary.

However...

When I run the binary (from `/opt/MyApp/MyApp`), and log the location from which it's trying to load `appsettings.json`, I see:

```
Loading settings from /var/tmp/.net/MyApp/jq1u11uk.4ap/appsettings.json
```

So my edited `/opt/MyApp/appsettings.json` is being ignored.

Is there some intended way to keep `appsettings.json` editable when using this publish option?

(This question was also asked at [How to handle Appsettings for .net core 3.1 self contained single file publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59366046/how-to-handle-appsettings-for-net-core-3-1-self-contained-single-file-publish), but was never answered in a way that solves being able to edit the file in-place.)

Comment: Why do you need to edit `appsettings.json`? You may change the settings values using environment variables

Comment: Thanks - appreciated that there are other approaches, but in this case am looking to be able to edit a text file.

Comment: This is also useful if you're mounting the appSettings dynamically using something like Vault by Hashicorp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this has been solved elsewhere - now working well after following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58307732/2847257